# Creating composite foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I am using this script in Mysql:

```
CONSTRAINT `customer_contact_geolocation_id_fk` FOREIGN  KEY(`customer_contact_geolocation`, `customer_contact_company_id`) 
REFERENCES `geolocation` (`geolocation_id`, `geolocation_company_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
)     
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

This is part of a create table statement. When I import it, It doesnt show errors. But when I check the table using workbench, the foreign key is not created. Also the fk it's not working in my app. Do I have to change some setting for this composite fk to work?

I am going to add a simpler script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `companies`;
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
`company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`company_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`company_address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`company_tax_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`company_minimun_margin` float NOT NULL,
`company_currency` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`company_fiscal_currency` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`company_max_rows` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`company_max_file_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geolocation`;

CREATE TABLE `geolocation` (
`geolocation_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`geolocation_company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`geolocation_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`geolocation_parent` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`geolocation_child` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`geolocation_id`,`geolocation_company_id`),
KEY `com_id_dem_com_id_fk` (`geolocation_company_id`),
CONSTRAINT `com_id_dem_com_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`geolocation_company_id`) REFERENCES    `companies` (`company_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I use the next fk, the fk doesnt show on workbench (it shows the next result:

```
     10:18:43   ALTER TABLE `geolocation` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`geolocation_parent`, `geolocation_company_id`) REFERENCES `geolocation` (`geolocation_id`, `geolocation_company_id`)    0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.136 sec
```

)

```
ALTER TABLE `geolocation`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`geolocation_parent`, `geolocation_company_id`)
REFERENCES `geolocation` (`geolocation_id`, `geolocation_company_id`);
```

If I change to this fk:

```
ALTER TABLE `geolocation`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`geolocation_parent`)
REFERENCES `geolocation` (`geolocation_id`);
```

Everything works great, but I need the composite fk.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: can you post the table structure of both the tables

Comment: i guess the keys should have same names

Comment: where are the other related tables? create a sql fiddle with all the tables involved

Comment: you can use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` this to debug the error in MySQL console

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with mysql it was with Mysql Workbench. Workbench wont show the fk, but it exists. 
I tried Toad and it shows it. Also I used "SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name" and it shows the desired output.

Thanks all for the help.

Regards,
Daniel